# Can't select the value from the suggestions in kendo AutoComplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have [kendo-autocomplete](/questions/tagged/kendo-autocomplete).

```
<input id="txtSearchText" style="height: 27px; width: 200px;" class="k-textbox" />
```

In [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript):

```
$("#txtSearchText").kendoAutoComplete({
  virtual: true,
  height: 210,
  itemHeight: 30,
  dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
    serverFiltering: true,
    serverPaging: true,
    pageSize: 28,
    transport: {
      read: {
        url: url,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        type: "Get"
      },
      parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
        return {
          searchText: options.filter.filters[0].value,
        }
      }
    }
  }),
  placeholder: "Search",
  enforceMinLength: true,
  minLength: 2,
  filter: "startswith",
  select: function(e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
})
```

The above is the [kendo-autocomplete](/questions/tagged/kendo-autocomplete) configuration.
From the `C#` controller, I am getting the `string[]`.
I am getting the suggestion list, but I am unable to select the value.

[image]

I am unable to select the value from the suggestions. What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you test this?: `select: function(e) {
    console.log(this.dataItem(e.item.index()));
  }`.

Comment: It's not even firing the select event. But I changed the controller, so that I will get the object back and added the dataTextField and value field. Working as expected right now.